# Does adding column to a DataFrame involve copying data?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas, internal

My question is about performance only, not semantics.

Does adding a new column to a df cause the data in the existing DataFrame to be physically copied to a new memory location (to ensure that the DataFrame occupies contiguous memory, for example)?

```
# using pandas 0.18.1, python 3.5
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(100)})
b = pd.Series(range(100))
df['b'] = b # is this operation expensive?
# equivalently df.loc[:, 'b'] = b
```

I know (from experimentation, couldn't find it in the documentation) that `df['b'] = b` will semantically create a copy of `b`, which obviously requires copying of underlying data. But I have no idea if the data in the other columns can stay where it was, or need to be moved sometimes.

Edit:

I know that adding a large number of columns is [expensive](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1502). I'm only asking about adding a single column.

I also know that adding a **row** requires copying of the data in some cases (or always? -- not sure) for an obvious reason that the items in a single column have to be in contiguous memory.

Comment: With `numpy` arrays (the underlying structure for most of Pandas), any `concatenate` involves creating a new larger array and copying ALL values to it (regardless of their relative size).  The copying mentioned in the Pandas issue applies to adding one or adding many columns, it's just more expensive if you do it iteratively.

Comment: @hpaulj then why is it advised (in both documentation and various write-ups about pandas) to avoid adding rows to DF, but no mention is made of adding columns?

Comment: If a dataframe is a 2d array, then adding columns is just as expensive as adding rows.  Dito if columns are `fields` of a structured array.  But the DF is a list of 1d arrays (columns) then adding columns would be easier.

Comment: @hpaulj so it's a list of 1d arrays? then the last sentence of your first comment only applies to rows not to columns right?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the Pandas documentation just how a DataFrame is implemented.  I'm guessing it uses a mix of structures, depending on how the data was provided, and what you ask it do with it.  It may be too complicated to resolve with a few timeit tests.

Answer (score 2):

I think from my experiments that `loc` is slowier and align new `Series` with different index the slowiest:

> But I have no idea if the data in the other columns can stay where it was, or need to be moved sometimes.

I think data are not moved, new columns are added to the end (maybe some exception can be here, but I dont know about it).

```
# using pandas 0.18.1, python 3.5
import pandas as pd
#len(df) = 10m
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10000000)})
b = pd.Series(range(10000000))
c = pd.Series(range(10000000), index=df.index)
df['b'] = b
df.loc[:, 'c'] = b
df['d'] = c
df.loc[:, 'e'] = c
print (df)

In [36]: %timeit df['b'] = b
10 loops, best of 3: 23.5 ms per loop

In [37]: %timeit df.loc[:, 'c'] = b
The slowest run took 5.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 40 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit df['d'] = c
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit df.loc[:, 'e'] = c
10 loops, best of 3: 39.5 ms per loop
```

But if change `index`:

```
# using pandas 0.18.1, python 3.5
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10000000)})
df.index = df.index + 15 
b = pd.Series(range(10000000))
c = pd.Series(range(10000000), index=df.index)
df['b'] = b
df.loc[:, 'c'] = b
df['d'] = c
df.loc[:, 'e'] = c
print (df)

In [41]: %timeit df['b'] = b
1 loop, best of 3: 656 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit df.loc[:, 'c'] = b
1 loop, best of 3: 735 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit df['d'] = c
10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit df.loc[:, 'e'] = c
10 loops, best of 3: 56.6 ms per loop
```

If add new row, it is fast, I think it depends of length of `Series`:

```
In [68]: %timeit df.loc[10000015, :] = pd.Series([1,2,3,2,4], index=df.columns)
1000 loops, best of 3: 274 µs per loop
```

But if add many rows, it is expensive and I think this can be avoided.

Comment: Seems plausible, but isn't there an official description of the internal data structure used to implement DataFrame to make sure?

Comment: But maybe some `pandas` guru explain your question better. Another option is create new question to [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) and `Jeff` maybe explain it better.